# Open cell for editing in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, button

What I wanted to achieve was to create a button that adds a new row and sets focus so typing can be done without additional clicks. But now I only set focus, but to start typing it is necessary to click on the cell.

How can I open a cell using a script, so a user can immediately start typing?
When I use `setCurrentCell` function, it only sets focus but I cannot start typing.

What I want to achieve:
[image]

Comment: I've tested it too. All of these do not work: `setCurrentCell(range)`, `setActiveRange(range)`, `range.Activate()`. They just change the focus, but they all require additional click if the function is called from a button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried variations of button types (inserting image, drawings and links to the specific cell receiving focus) with no success. However, regardless of what you use as the button, after you select it, if you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> you will get something like this...

[image: set focus button example]

Once it's selected hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Then you'll be able to start typing.