# Have to press ESC after script runs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am running this script to copy a part number to an invoice:

```
function StockToInvoice() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

// Move to first cell in row
mycolumn = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getColumn();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -(mycolumn-1)).activateAsCurrentCell()

// Store cell value
stockcode = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getValue()

// write to next empty Code cell in the Shop sheet
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Shop'), true);
{spreadsheet.getRange('A20').getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(stockcode).offset(0, 1).activate()
}; 
}`
```

After it runs I have to press ESC in order to type into the cell it finishes at.

Any idea how to release the cell automatically please?

Comment: How are you running the script? P.S. Google Apps Script interactions with the user-interface are very limited i.e. it can't automatically open a menu / contextual menu, put a cell in edit mode, among other limitations.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/55088373/1595451

Comment: Hi Rubén, It's started by an attached button. It runs fine just the cell is "locked" afterwards and you have to press ESC or mouse click the cell to enable typing

Comment: Just mapped "1" to the script and if I run it with CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+1 then it works and the cell is available

Comment: Thanks for you replies Ben C. It looks to be too convoluted compared to pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> (pressing four keys Vs one). Better to use the macros built-in menu or a custom menu. See  https://stackoverflow.com/q/57859071/1595451.

Comment: Now found out that this is something that happens (and cannot be changed) if the script is started by pressing a button. Works "normally" if started from a menu or shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

While pressing `ESC` is enough to allow writing, it might be appropriate to use [prompt](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#promptprompt) to type the desired value:

```
function StockToInvoice() {
  // ...stuff...
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(stockcode).offset(0, 1).activate();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const response = ui.prompt("Enter cell value");
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(response.getResponseText());
}
```

Otherwise, just call your function using other methods instead of buttons.

Comment: Thanks for that -Iamblichus I think just not using the buttons is the best way in this instance but you script might come in handy for something else. Thanks again